# Does JPanel have built in support for dragging and docking/pinning components?

Tags: jpanel

My goal is to make docked components have the standard rearrange and resize behaviors. For example I have the main large component in the middle and a small component running the length of the right side. I grab the handle of the component on the right and drag it to the left, and it snaps to the left side instead, effectively trading places with the large component. Something like this:
[image: pokeymans]

And what's described [here](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=73), but for java.

With enough work I could probably reinvent the wheel using the JPanel methods I'm aware of, but I suspect its already supported to some degree, or at the very least has been repeated enough that there are good examples of how to make something that's intuitive to anyone who's docked items in other programs.

What I need is a starting point, if this sort of docking is officially supported, what terms should I search for to learn about it? If its not, how does a typical JPanel programmer make something that feels like the sort of drag-to-dock you find in applications like Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

I started using [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/Dockable.htm). It appears to use some libraries that do exactly what I wanted.

I'm still open to better, standard solutions.